# Couldnt make RDP connection to Windows instance in AWS

Tags: remote-desktop, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created windows 12 R2 Base EC2 instance with VPC in AWS.
But I am unable to do RDP to that instance.

I have checked the following things :
1. Instance has elastic IP with IPv4 public Ip
2 .Security group : Inbound: Type :RDP ,Protocol:TCP, Port range: 3389 , Source :0.0.0.0/0 .Outbound : All traffic, destination :0.0.0.0/0.
3. Route Table :
Destination 0.0.0.0/0
Target **************** 
Status Active
Propagated No

But still I am not able do RDP connection.
Any suggestions would be very much helpful to me.

Comment: Did you try to connect from different locations (home, office ...etc.)? And also check the network ACL for the subnet the instance was launched in

Comment: Open all ports to see if that works. Check your network ACLs. You should probably keep your acronyms consistent, RDP = Remote Desktop Protocol, RDS = Relational Database Service